# Add a params in the path of URL under condition with retrofit

Tags: kotlin, interface, retrofit, okhttp

I have created an API like below:

```
interface listProd {
  @GET("v1/{type}")
  fun getProduct(
      @Path("type") type: String): Observable<Response>
}
```

Now I need to add a param to make it as below:

```
interface listProd {
  @GET("v1/{type}?preview=true")
  fun getProduct(
      @Path("type") type: String): Observable<Response>
}
```

But I do not want to have it all the time. The goal is to see how I can add `?preview=true` under a boolean condition, I do not want to have multiple interface but a smart way to add or not it.

the condition can be boolean pass in the `getProduct` which trigger the append or not of the the `?preview=true`

Any idea 
Thanks

Comment: doesn't  that api response with `preview=false`

Comment: @TejasPandya I want to avoid the param to appears in the path if not required.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an optional query parameter for this:

```
@GET("v1/{type}")
fun getProduct(
    @Path("type") type: String,
    @Query("preview") preview: Boolean?
): Observable<Response>
```

With the caveat that passing in `true` or `false` will include that parameter, while `null` will omit it altogether.